# Pythagorean inequality in l1 norm for projection onto simplex

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, projection

Let $x$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^d$, let $z$ be the projection of $x$ onto the $d-1$ dimensional simplex ($z^\top \mathbf{1}= 1$ and $z \succeq 0$). So basically

$$z = \arg\min_w \{\rVert x-w\rVert_2 \,\,|\,\, w^\top \mathbf{1} = 1\,,w\succeq 0 \} $$

Let $y$ be any other point in the simplex. Is it true that $\rVert z- y\rVert_1 \leq \rVert x- y\rVert_1$?

I could prove this for $\mathbb{R}^2$ but not sure how to generalize it to $\mathbb{R}^d$. The above inequality actually holds for *Euclidean* norm (not sure if it has an official name but some people refer to it as the Pythagorean inequality for projection onto convex sets)

but I'm interested in **L1** norm instead. Any leads/related problems are greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: When writing $z^\top 1 = 1$, is the first $1$ the column vector in $\Bbb{R}^d$ consisting of all $1$s? That is, is the simplex the set of all vectors in $\Bbb{R}^d$ in the positive orthant whose components sum to $1$?

Comment: @user804886, yes sorry for being unclear, first one should be a vector of all 1s. So it's the set of probability vector

Comment: The relation $\|x\|_2\leq\|x\|_1$ makes me think what you're looking for holds

Comment: @iarbel84 good point, in fact, we can show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}} \rVert z-y\rVert_1 \leq \rVert z-y\rVert_2 \leq \rVert x-y\rVert_2 \leq \rVert x - y\rVert_1$. Getting rid of the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}$ seems hard though

Comment: I'm pretty sure this does hold, but a formal proof with any kind of elegance eludes me. My PhD is on projections, and I can confirm that this property does not hold for general convex sets in $\Bbb{R}^d$, but I think the specific structure of this set, being a face of the $1$-sphere, will mean the $2$-projection will lie inside the $1$-projection.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Pythagorean inequality only holds for inner-product norms rather than all norms. Thus this result may not hold for $\ell_1$ norm. One can refer to this book[``Introduction to Online Convex Optimization''](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.05207.pdf) (Page. 159) and this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616638/is-obtuse-angle-criterion-held-for-l-p-norm) for more details.

Comment: True, but it might still work with a different type of setting. You can check to see if Bregman distance will work, which is detailed in Chen and Teboulle's work https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0803026

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstanding your reply. This paper proves the convergence of PPA for Bregman’s distance, but I really don't know why Pythagorean inequality hold.

Comment: You can use some convex function that will hold the Bregman distance properties w.r.t. the l-1 norm (for example, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \log x_i$). It's a long shot, but maybe you'll be able to construct what you're looking for - possibly by using the Three-point Lemma from the article.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but it seems that even for $d=2$ the claim fails. Consider $x=(\frac{4.4}{9}, \frac{5.5}{9})$. Then $z=\frac{x}{1.1}=(\frac{4}{9}, \frac{5}{9})$. If we take $y=(\frac{3}{9}, \frac{6}{9})$, then $\|x-y\|_{1}=\frac{1.9}{9}$, while $\|z-y\|_{1}=\frac{2}{9}$.